# Eclipse C++ doesn't create project folder hierarchy

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, project

Foreword:
It's awful sutiation. I love Eclipse IDE and don't want to change it. Please, don't advice using Microsoft Visual Studio instead of Eclipse. It doesn't fit me. I need cross platform IDE with all power of plugin possibilities so I need Eclipse working with C++.

I'm new to C++. But experienced in working with Java Eclipse. So I hope you can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Question:
When I try creating a new C++ project (tried on both MacOS and Windows 7 64 bit) I name it and select a toolchain. After "Finish" clicked I see that there is no any folder in project except "src" with the main class in it.
The "Problems" tab shows a bunch of problems. It seems to be the problem with the toolchain paths. 
You can see the project hierarchy on my screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW32e.png

I tried both "Hello World C++ Project" and "Empty Project" but nothing does make sense. Also tried to choose different toolchains. No way... Tried lots of tutorials and it seems to be easy to create a new project as you can see in those tutorials. The "included" folder and "bin" folder are in place and all is OK! Why!? Need your help, guys!

Comment: Is the toolchain instaled at some place on your pc?

Comment: Yes! I've installed both Cygwin and MinGW.

Comment: Visibly not in the way that Eclipse expects (the issues state that it doesn't find the compiler).

Comment: I guess. But I don't know how to fix that. I've heard about paths properties problem but cannot fix my problem by using those methods.

Comment: What the!? Really, people.. I have nothing to say.. Tried reinstalling Cygwin and Eclipse for C++.. But I'm stuck.. http://i.imgur.com/NLwvD.png?1 http://i.imgur.com/F9lxT.png?1 What's wrong!? I'm fighting with that IDE all day long!!!

Comment: Seems the compiler cannot find the standard library. Maybe manually adding it to the compiler options or in the library part of eclipse will solve it.

Comment: No way. It doesnt work. It just pissing me off because it doesnt make damn standard project folder hierarchy. It just creates that damn "src" folder without ANYTHING MORE... No binaries folder. No include folder. Nothing else! Sorry for my weird behaviour but I'm really angry now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is closed on Mac OS. Installed GCC package for Mac OS from here https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer. It was a miracle (because XCode was already installed when the problem occured) but everything is ok for now! It's time to close it for Windows 7. I think I should follow that tutorial and set PATH property directly in the OS http://www.banym.de/eclipse/install-eclipse-cdt-on-windows-7